# Page wont Load computed ASP WEB variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I fix this form, I need to redirect the result to a different page after the button "Display offer is pressed"; the main problem here is that I can't save the data and redirecting it.  The 2nd page should look something like this:

```
The price for the vehicle you have configured is [All the options selected/computed]
The offer was issued on [Calendar date1] and remains valid until [Calendar date2]
```

I have tested something using  Cache...still no result.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
GetData()
End Sub
1 reference
Private Sub GetData()
lblName.Text = Cache("Name").ToString
1blPrice.Text = Cache("Price").ToString
lblofferDate.Text = Cache("offerDate").ToString
1blofferExpiration.Text = Cache("ExpirationDate").ToString
End Sub
```

1st page - Main FORM.

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 204px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            width: 843px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .auto-style5 {
            height: 24px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table class="auto-style1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Last Name:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="First Name:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Offer date:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Calendar ID="calOfferDate" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" CellPadding="4" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="180px" Width="200px">
                            <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" />
                            <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#808080" />
                            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                            <TitleStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
                            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
                            <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
                        </asp:Calendar>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Offer expiration date:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Calendar ID="calExpirationDate" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" CellPadding="4" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" Height="180px" Width="200px">
                            <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="7pt" />
                            <NextPrevStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                            <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#808080" />
                            <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#666666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <SelectorStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                            <TitleStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" />
                            <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
                            <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
                        </asp:Calendar>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr />

        </div>
        <p class="auto-style3">
            <strong>Set up your car</strong></p>
        <table class="auto-style4">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style5">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Equipment level"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style5">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="20,000">Standard</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="22,000">Evolved</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="27,000">Advanced</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="32,000">Premium</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Warranty type"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>Standard (2 years)</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Extended (5 years)</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>

                     
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Optionals"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblOptionals" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblOptionals" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="727px">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1,000">Alloys wheels</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1,500">Climatronic</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1,300">Automatic pilot</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1,000">Road alert</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="850">Navigation</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style5">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="Discounts"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td class="auto-style5"><strong><em>
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbListDiscounts" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="auto-style5" Width="394px" TextAlign="Left">
                        <asp:ListItem>Whole payment</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>CASCO insurance</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                    </em></strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnDisplayOffer" runat="server" BackColor="Red" ForeColor="#CCCCCC" Height="20px" Text="Display offer" Width="101px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Display button in FORM

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnDisplayOffer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayOffer.Click
        Response.Redirect("Offer.aspx")
    End Sub
    Public Sub CreateCache()
        Cache("Name") = txtFirstName.Text & " " & txtLastName.Text
        Cache("offerDate") = calOfferDate.SelectedDate
        Cache("ExpirationDate") = calExpirationDate.SelectedDate
        Dim price As Integer

        If DropDownList1.Items(0).Selected = True Then
            price = 20000
        ElseIf DropDownList1.Items(1).Selected = True Then
            price = 22000
        ElseIf DropDownList1.Items(2).Selected = True Then
            price = 27000
        Else
            price = 32000
        End If
        If RadioButtonList1.Items(1).Selected = True Then
            price = price + 2000
        End If



        If cbListDiscounts.Items(0).Selected = True Then
            price = price - (price * 0.1)

        End If
        If cbListDiscounts.Items(1).Selected = True Then
            price = price - 1000
        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub rblOptionals_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rblOptionals.SelectedIndexChanged
        If rblOptionals.SelectedValue.Equals("Yes") Then
            cblOptionals.Visible = True
        Else
            cblOptionals.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Cache is not the right choice: its scope is application wide, meaning all users see the same data. Use Session for user specific data

Comment: Your click handler just redirects and doesn't call CreateCache. And that calculates a price and forgets it

Answer (score 2):

Just code out your button code. You click on that button - it saves some data, and then does a simple response.Redirect.

```
Protected Sub btnDisplayOffer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayOffer.Click
    SaveMyData
    Response.Redirect("Offer.aspx")
End Sub

Sub SaveMyData

    Session("Name") = txtFirstName.Text & " " & txtLastName.Text
    Session("offerDate") = calOfferDate.SelectedDate
    Session("ExpirationDate") = calExpirationDate.SelectedDate
    .etc .etc. etc.
End Sub
```

Now, in the target page, you can in on-load do this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    if IsPostBack = False then
        GetData()
    end if
End Sub

Private Sub GetData()
    lblName.Text = Session("Name")
    1blPrice.Text = Session("Price")
    lblofferDate.Text = Session("offerDate")
    1blofferExpiration.Text = Session("ExpirationDate")
End Sub
```

and as noted  always remember to check IsPostPack = False. That is your FIRST one time page load - so inside of that code block then becomes just like say a VB6 or ms-access form load event - the first time is where your load up code goes - without that if IsPostBack = False, then that code will run every time - including for buttons etc. that you drop on the form - and thus those controls will be re-set each time you use a button or any event on that page - as a coding habit - put your page load up code inside of the IsPostBack=False code stub - do NOT forget to have that code block - make it  habit - even when you think you don't need to!!!!